# How to hide elements of li with values less than input number

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a form that takes an input from the user as a number. Below is unordered list of elements with numbers.

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" autocomplete="off">    
<ul id="myUL">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<script>
  function myFunction(){
    let input = parseInt(document.querySelector('myInput').value);
    let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      let number = parseInt(li[i].value);
      if (number < input) {
        li[i].style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = '';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If any of these numbers is less than input then element should hide dynamically. They're not hiding.

[SOLVED]

```
function myFunction(){
let input = parseInt(document.querySelector('#myInput').value);
let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  let number = parseInt(li[i].innerHTML);
  if (number < input) {
    li[i].style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    li[i].style.display = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your selector is invalid.  `myInput` should be `#myInput` as it's an id.

Comment: `parseInt(li[i].value);` is also invalid as `li` do not have a value.  They have `innerText` or `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can pass in the `this.value` on the inline binding so you do not have to look that up
- Since you gave the `ul` an id, you might as well use that as part of your selector to find the associated li elements
- Parse the `innerText`, rather than the `value` as `li` elements do not have a value
- You can use a ternary statement for setting the display property

```js
function myFunction(inputValue) {
  inputValue = parseInt(inputValue || '0');
  let lis = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL li');
  
  lis.forEach(function(li){
    let liValue = parseInt(li.innerText);
    
    li.style.display = ( liValue < inputValue ? 'none' : '');
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)" autocomplete="off">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `innerHTML` or `innerText`. And also use `document.querySelector('#myInput')`. And convert li to `Array` using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and loop using [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) it looks better

```js
function myFunction(){
      let input = parseInt(document.querySelector('#myInput').value);
      let li = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('li'));
      
      li.forEach(item => {
        let number = parseInt(item.innerHTML);
        if (number < input) {
          item.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
          item.style.display = '';
        }
      })
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" autocomplete="off">    
<ul id="myUL">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` does not return an array. I did `Array.from(document.getElementByTagName("li"))` to return an array.

Also you should use `innerText` instead of `value`. `value` is only available for `select`, `input` and `textarea`.

```js
    function myFunction(){
      let input = parseInt(document.querySelector('#myInput').value);
      let li = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('li'));
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        let number = parseInt(li[i].innerText);
        if (number < input) {
          li[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
          li[i].style.display = '';
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" autocomplete="off">    
<ul id="myUL">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: @Taplar Because I didn't want to change what his wrote.

Comment: But you did change it.  You added to it, making it two method calls, rather than changing it to the method that would allow just one method call.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` will return an object with all the `li`. Convert them to than array using Object.values. It will return an array of all the `li` elements
QuerySelector was wrong. You have to use `#` for id

```js
function myFunction(){
      let input = parseInt(document.querySelector('#myInput').value);
      let li = Object.values(document.getElementsByTagName('li'));
       for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        number = parseInt(li[i].innerHTML);
        if (number < input) {
          li[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
          li[i].style.display = '';
        }
      }}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" autocomplete="off">    
<ul id="myUL">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using # to find an ID with query selecter. Also, the numbers are in the `innerText`.

```
 function myFunction(){
      let input = document.querySelector('#myInput').value;
      let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        number = parseInt(li[i].innerText); 
        if (number < parseInt(input)) {
          li[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
          li[i].style.display = '';
        }
      }
    }
```